# import modules within other function

Tags: python, python-3.x, import

I want to import modules , depending on something (e.g. user args input) and use the provided functions inside this module then.
But it lets me only import at file beginning, not within my main function. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when i was testing this problem i got no errors, this was my code:

```
import random

global x
condition=random.randint(0, 1)
x=1
def function():
    if x == condition:
        import time
        time.sleep(1)
        print("imported function correctly!")
    else:
        try:
            time.sleep(1)
        except:
            print("conditions not met and module is not imported")

function()
```

Comment: I used a simple time module to test my program, when I ran it, it waited the specified time

Comment: How is that possible? Is it python 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use importlib

```
>>userinput='math'
>>import importlib
>>my_module=importlib.import_module(userinput)
>>print(my_module.pow(4,2))
16
```

I think this satisfies what you are asking for!

```
import importlib
u='math'
def func():
  m=importlib.import_module(u)
  print(m.sqrt(4))

func()
```